# Typerscript: Union type with Enum | string | number returns string | number

Tags: typescript

I have an union type

```
type Preset = `${TextPreset}` | TextPresetKey;
```

where `TextPreset` is an Enum and `TextPresetKey` is a `keyof typeof TEXT_PRESET_KEY` where `TEXT_PRESET_KEY` is just an *as const* object typed as `{ [key: string]: string }`

My question comes from the fact that when I hover in my IDE `Preset` it shows:
`type Preset = string | number`

But if I delete `TextPresetKey` from `Preset` like

```
type Preset = `${TextPreset}`;
```

it shows what I expect:

```
type Preset = "HIGHLIGHT_L" | "HIGHLIGHT_M" | "HIGHLIGHT_S" | "TITLE_L" | "TITLE_M" | "TITLE_S" | "BODY_L" | "BODY_L_STRONG" | "BODY_M" | "BODY_M_STRONG" | "BODY_S" | "BODY_S_STRONG" | "BODY_XS" | "BODY_XS_STRONG"
```

Anyone can tell me why the union is not working as I expect?
I expect something like

```
type Preset = "HIGHLIGHT_L" | "HIGHLIGHT_M" | "HIGHLIGHT_S" | "TITLE_L" | "TITLE_M" | "TITLE_S" | "BODY_L" | "BODY_L_STRONG" | "BODY_M" | "BODY_M_STRONG" | "BODY_S" | "BODY_S_STRONG" | "BODY_XS" | "BODY_XS_STRONG" | string | number
```

Thxs!

Example
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-d8j9rh?file=/index.ts

Hover `Preset`, you'll get `string | number`. Remove `TextPresetKey` and you'll get the enum on hover.

I tried the union type and did not worked as expected

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]? A simple enum, your type above, code that when we look at  the type, we'll see what you're seeing?

Comment: ^^, as above a working example would be good, a great place to create one is on TypeScripts website -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/Q  You can then copy the link in the URL and add to your question.

Comment: Sorry i did not post this example before :)
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-d8j9rh?file=/index.ts

Comment: Because your widening the type `HIGHLIGHT_L` etc, can all be `string`.  Do you need `string | number`?   Would `700s | HIGHLIGHT_L` etc work,  If so keep your type for `TEXT_PRESET_KEY` narrow, you can do this by just removing `{ [key: string]: string }` the implicit typing will keep it narrow.

Comment: you're right @Keith

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript will remove any literal string types from a union with `string`, because they are already contained within `string` so not necessary to include in the union. So for example `'a' | 'b' | string` is collapsed down to just `string`.

Of course, this causes problems because it doesn't provide any nice autocomplete suggestions. One current workaround for this is to use `string & {}` instead of `string` in your union. TypeScript seems to tag this as a modified type, and so it won't collapse the union down in the same way. So, for example, `'a' | 'b' | (string & {})` will *not* collapse down to just `string`, and you will get autocomplete suggestions for `'a'` and `'b'`.

Unfortunately, this is finnicky if you're not adding `string` to union directly - if you just try to apply `& {}` to the part of your union that it inherits its `string` member from that won't be good enough. Even if you just use `NonNullable<string>` it won't work, and `NonNullable<T> = T & {}`. So if you'd like to use this method with your union, you would need to change how it's constructed.

The idea of changing the way TypeScript behaves so unions that include `string` and string literal types won't collapse was [discussed during a design meeting](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55105) earlier this year. It made it into the [TypeScript 5.3 iteration plan](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55486), but as far as I can tell it didn't make it into the [TypeScript 5.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-3-beta/) beta that launched a week ago. It was in the 5.2 iteration plan too, though it also didn't ship with 5.2. I'm hopefully we might see this feature shipped next year, though.